# UITableView not showing new cell data

Tags: uitableview, ios4, viewwillappear

The first time my UITableView loads, my cellForRowAtIndexPath method gets correctly called.  The subsequent times I show my IUTableView, this method is not called and the old data is shown.

Neither are the viewWillAppear method nor the numberOfRowsInSelection called.

Anyone know what could be wrong?

Thanks
Deshawn

Comment: Hm. `ViewWillAppear` should work...

Answer (score 0):

When you get your new data, fire `-reloadData` on the table view. It'll run all its data source methods to get a fresh look at its source data.

Don't tie that reload on the display of the view. Tie it to when you receive the new data.